# React outer div assigned wrong id

Tags: reactjs

I have render functions that look something like this:

```
render_login: function() {
  return <div>
    <div className='form_container'>
      <div className='logo' />
      {
        this.state.alert ?
        <div className='alert fading'>
          { this.some_prop }
        </div> :
        null
      }
      { this.some_render() }
    </div>
    { extra_auth_reqd ? this.some_other_render : null }
    { local_conn_btn_present ? <SomeComponent /> : null }
  </div>;
},

render: function() {
  if(this.some_prop) {
    return <div>
      <SomeOtherComponent />;
    </div>;
  } else {
    return this.render_login();
  }
}
```

My issue only has to do with `render_login`. When `return this.render_login` is run in Chrome, the outer wrapping div gets an id of `validatedFactory_view` like so: [image: Chrome]

But it works properly and sets the id to `login_view` (the name of the file) in Firefox like so: [image: Firefox]

Why might this be happening? I could just manually set the id to `login_view`, which solves the problem, but I would like to understand what causes this behavior.

Comment: where does the `validatedFactory_view` class comes from?

Comment: That's the thing, it's nowhere in my repo, I've grepped for it. I think it's something from React itself.

Comment: did you grep inside `node_modules`?

Comment: I was mistaken, I used `git grep` before, but it didn't grep inside directories that were ignored. I did a general `grep` across my repo and found some instances of `validatedFactory`, namely in `js/react/src/core/ReactDescriptorValidator.js`. Looks like it's used in a method that creates a factory to validate descriptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue after some debugging on Chrome and Firefox. I'm setting the `id` of the `div` in my top level `app_view` with code that looks something like this:

```
render: function() {
  var name = this.state.view.name || this.state.view.view_name;
  return <div id={name + "_view"} className="view">
    ... some random stuff
  </div>;
}
```

In Firefox, `this.state.view.name` was `null`, but in Chrome, it was `validatedFactory`. After a little more digging, I found that in both browsers, the `this.state.view` was pointing to a function within `vendor/js/react/src/core/ReactDescriptorValidator.js`'s `createFactory` function called `validatedFactory`. The code looks something like this:

```
var ReactDescriptorValidator = {
  createFactory: function(factory, propTypes, contextTypes) {
    var validatedFactory = function(props, children) {
    var descriptor = factory.apply(this, arguments);

    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      validateChildKeys(arguments[i], descriptor.type);
    }
    ...
    return validatedFactory;
  }
};

module.exports = ReactDescriptorValidator;
```

As you can see here, the `validatedFactory` is essentially a wrapper to the descriptor factory that is passed into the `createFactory` function. It is a variable that points to an anonymous function, and it is this function that we are calling `.name` on.

I did a little more digging about why there is a discrepancy between the name in Chrome and Firefox, and it turns out that Firefox actually doesn't have support for inferred names on anonymous functions, as seen [here](http:////https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). Until recently, Chrome didn't even have support for this so everything was working fine because it too would return `null` for `name`, and my code would just end up using `view_name`. Mystery solved. I'll need to look into if there is any reason we're specifically checking `view.name`, and if not, remove it.

Big thanks to @matriay for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: well that's I was saying to you! :D

Comment: You were right! I was just so sure it had to be something with React source code for some reason. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're not executing `this.render_login`, you missed the parenthesis. Second, I don't think that class comes from that component but from the parent component instead.

Comment: The omission of the parentheses was a mistake on my part, I have edited it. And if the ID was coming from the parent, why don't chrome and Firefox behave the same way? I have nothing in my repo with that text, I have grepped.

Comment: what modules do you have installed? react adds no `id` to my elements

Comment: I have many many modules installed, are you saying that React doesn't add an `id` to your wrapping `div`? How does React know which div to apply your styling on?

Comment: React uses the `data-reactid` attribute, look for it in your screenshots

Comment: are the stylings not still applied by the DOM element's `id`? When I change the `id` of the `div` to `login_view` in chrome, the stylings are applied properly.

Comment: where did you define your styles? if they are common css selectors makes sense that they're id-dependant and react-independant

Comment: They are defined in `css/login.scss`, they use common css selectors.

Comment: Without more information i cannot tell you where that `validatedFactory_view` appears in chrome and `render_login` in firefox because **react does not add any `id` attribute by itself**, it must be some other module you have that is using `validatedFactory` as metadata and constructing that id (only in chrome, odd) despite what you've seen in your grep, I found the same in github but it does nothing about `id`s. For styling you probably should be using classes which are easier with https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

Comment: Martiary I found the reason it was breaking, as I have detailed in my answer. Thank you for your time and help with this issue!